# Mongodb find all collection after update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm using mongodb with node js. 
After updating table collection

`db.collection('tables').update(something)`

And I try to get all collection

`db.collection('tables').find()`

But I get old collection with not updated tables. 
So how I can update and get all updated collection?

Comment: This might help you get started, http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#update also, `update` is deprecated.

Comment: I noticed you posted the same question with more details (including actual code instead of a "something" placeholder) a few hours later. If you have additional information to clarify a question, please edit the original question instead of posting a duplicate. Specific details like a snippet of the code you are trying to troubleshoot and your versions of MongoDB driver and server will greatly improve the chances of someone being able to help with your issue ;-)